How to resize table in HTML after clicking a button?
I have a table where I can hide some stuff with a click of a button "Ocultar Informacao Adicional", but when I hide these labels, textfields, etc I can´t resize the table and it stays with a huge blank space.
I've tried height:auto, height:100%, display: none but none of those seemed to work


Here's my HTML


<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="width: 980px; position: relative;" class="tableEdit">

  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th width="280px">Fases</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr wicket:id="tabelaFase">
      <td>
        <div class="tdContentInput">

          <div class="labelDesc" style="width: 280px; margin-top: 10px;">
            <label>Fase número : </label>
            <label wicket:id="nome" class="bold"></label>
          </div>
          <div class="clearBoth labelAndValue width400">
            <label>Entrada em funcionamento do Estabelecimento</label>
            <div class="calendar">
              <input wicket:id="dataInicioFuncionamento" type="text" class="tdData" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="groupButtons">
            <input type="submit" value="Visualizar informação adicional" wicket:id="expandir" />
            <input type="submit" value="Ocultar informação adicional" wicket:id="ocultar" />

          </div>
          <div class="clearBoth labelAndValue width260">
            <label wicket:id="lblApPrgFunc">Aprovação do Programa Funcional</label>
            <div class="calendar">
              <input wicket:id="dataAprovFuncional" type="text" class="tdData" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="labelAndCheckBox na width130">
            <input wicket:id="naAprovFuncionalcb" type="checkbox" />
            <label wicket:id="lblnaApPrgFunc">Não Disponível</label>
          </div>
          <div class="clearBoth labelAndValue width260">
            <label wicket:id="lblAncConProj">Anúncio do concurso para o projeto</label>
            <div class="calendar">
              <input wicket:id="dataConcursoProjeto" type="text" class="tdData" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="labelAndCheckBox na width130">
            <input wicket:id="naConcursoProjetocb" type="checkbox" />
            <label wicket:id="lblnaAncConProj">Não Disponível</label>
          </div>
          <div class="clearBoth labelAndValue width260">
            <label wicket:id="lblAdjProj">Adjudicação do projeto</label>
            <div class="calendar">
              <input wicket:id="dataAdjudicacaoProjeto" type="text" class="tdData" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="labelAndCheckBox na width130">
            <input wicket:id="naAdjudicacaoProjetocb" type="checkbox" />
            <label wicket:id="lblnaAdjProj">Não Disponível</label>
          </div>
          <div class="clearBoth labelAndValue width260">
            <label wicket:id="lblAproProj">Aprovação do projeto</label>
            <div class="calendar">
              <input wicket:id="dataAprovacaoProjeto" type="text" class="tdData" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="labelAndCheckBox na width130">
            <input wicket:id="naAprovacaoProjetocb" type="checkbox" />
            <label wicket:id="lblnaAproProj">Não Disponível</label>
          </div>
          <div class="clearBoth labelAndValue width260">
            <label wicket:id="lblAncConEmp">Anúncio do concurso para a empreitada</label>
            <div class="calendar">
              <input wicket:id="dataConcursoConstrucao" type="text" class="tdData" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="labelAndCheckBox na width130">
            <input wicket:id="naConcursoConstrucaocb" type="checkbox" />
            <label wicket:id="lblnaAncConEmp">Não Disponível</label>
          </div>
          <div class="clearBoth labelAndValue width260">
            <label wicket:id="lblAdjEmp">Adjudicação da empreitada</label>
            <div class="calendar">
              <input wicket:id="dataAdjudicacaoConst" type="text" class="tdData" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="labelAndCheckBox na width130">
            <input wicket:id="naAdjudicacaoConstcb" type="checkbox" />
            <label wicket:id="lblnaAdjEmp">Não Disponível</label>
          </div>
          <div class="clearBoth labelAndValue width260">
            <label wicket:id="lblRcpProvObra">Recepção provisória da obra</label>
            <div class="calendar">
              <input wicket:id="dataRecepcaoProvisoria" type="text" class="tdData" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="labelAndCheckBox na width130">
            <input wicket:id="naRecepcaoProvisoriacb" type="checkbox" />
            <label wicket:id="lblnaRcpProvObra">Não Disponível</label>
          </div>
          <div class="clearBoth labelAndValue width260">
            <label wicket:id="lblIngEdfHsp">Inauguração do Edifício Hospitalar</label>
            <div class="calendar">
              <input wicket:id="dataInauguracao" type="text" class="tdData" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="labelAndCheckBox na width130">
            <input wicket:id="naInauguracaocb" type="checkbox" />
            <label wicket:id="lblnaIngEdfHsp">Não Disponível</label>
          </div>
          <div class="clearBoth labelAndValue width260">
            <label wicket:id="lblRcpDefObra">Recepção definitiva da obra</label>
            <div class="calendar">
              <input wicket:id="dataRecepcaoDefinitiva" type="text" class="tdData" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="labelAndCheckBox na width130">
            <input wicket:id="naRecepcaoDefinitivacb" type="checkbox" />
            <label wicket:id="lblnaRcpDefObra">Não Disponível</label>
          </div>

        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
  </tfoot>
</table>




You probably mean JavaScript, not Java.  If you do mean Java, please clarify.  What framework(s) do you use, what does your code currently look like?  Provide details and a code listing.

There are many ways to achieve this effect.
One simple way (ie. without involving animated effects) is simply to add click events to each of the two buttons, such that one will add and the other will remove a class which applies the style rule display: none to all of the table rows beneath the row with the buttons.

Working Example:


const tableEdit = document.querySelector('.tableEdit');
const expandButton = document.querySelector('#expandir');
const hideButton = document.querySelector('#ocultar');

const toggleAdditionalInfo = (e) => {
  switch (e.currentTarget.id) {
    case ('expandir'): tableEdit.classList.remove('hideAdditionalRows'); break;
    case ('ocultar'): tableEdit.classList.add('hideAdditionalRows'); break;
  }
}

expandButton.addEventListener('click', toggleAdditionalInfo);
hideButton.addEventListener('click', toggleAdditionalInfo);
.tableEdit {
  position: relative;
  width: 600px;
  border: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

td {
  padding: 12px;
  border: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

button#expandir,
.tableEdit.hideAdditionalRows button#ocultar {
  opacity: 0.5;
  pointer-events: none;
}

button#ocultar,
.tableEdit.hideAdditionalRows button#expandir {
  opacity: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
  pointer-events: auto;
}

.tableEdit.hideAdditionalRows tr.buttonRow ~ tr {
  display: none;
}
<table class="tableEdit" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th width="280px">Fases</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  
  <tbody>
    <tr id="tabelaFase">
      <td class="labelDesc">
        <label>Fase número : </label>
        <label id="nome" class="bold"></label>
      </td>
    </tr>  

    <tr>
      <td class="clearBoth labelAndValue width400">
        <label>Entrada em funcionamento do Estabelecimento</label>
        <div class="calendar">
          <input id="dataInicioFuncionamento" type="text" class="tdData" />
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>  

    <tr class="buttonRow">
      <td class="groupButtons">
        <button type="button" id="expandir">Visualizar informação adicional</button>
        <button type="button" id="ocultar">Ocultar informação adicional</button>
      </td>
    </tr>  

    <tr>
      <td class="clearBoth labelAndValue width260">
        <label id="lblApPrgFunc">Aprovação do Programa Funcional</label>
        <div class="calendar">
          <input id="dataAprovFuncional" type="text" class="tdData" />
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>  

    <tr>
      <td class="labelAndCheckBox na width130">
        <input id="naAprovFuncionalcb" type="checkbox" />
        <label id="lblnaApPrgFunc">Não Disponível</label>
      </td>
    </tr>  

    <tr>
      <td class="clearBoth labelAndValue width260">
        <label id="lblAncConProj">Anúncio do concurso para o projeto</label>
        <div class="calendar">
          <input id="dataConcursoProjeto" type="text" class="tdData" />
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>  

    <tr>
      <td class="labelAndCheckBox na width130">
        <input id="naConcursoProjetocb" type="checkbox" />
        <label id="lblnaAncConProj">Não Disponível</label>
      </td>
    </tr>  

    <tr>
      <td class="clearBoth labelAndValue width260">
        <label id="lblAdjProj">Adjudicação do projeto</label>
        <div class="calendar">
          <input id="dataAdjudicacaoProjeto" type="text" class="tdData" />
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>  

    <tr>
      <td class="labelAndCheckBox na width130">
        <input id="naAdjudicacaoProjetocb" type="checkbox" />
        <label id="lblnaAdjProj">Não Disponível</label>
      </td>
    </tr>  

    <tr>
      <td class="clearBoth labelAndValue width260">
        <label id="lblAproProj">Aprovação do projeto</label>
        <div class="calendar">
          <input id="dataAprovacaoProjeto" type="text" class="tdData" />
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>  

    <tr>
      <td class="labelAndCheckBox na width130">
        <input id="naAprovacaoProjetocb" type="checkbox" />
        <label id="lblnaAproProj">Não Disponível</label>
      </td>
    </tr>  

    <tr>
      <td class="clearBoth labelAndValue width260">
        <label id="lblAncConEmp">Anúncio do concurso para a empreitada</label>
        <div class="calendar">
          <input id="dataConcursoConstrucao" type="text" class="tdData" />
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>  

    <tr>
      <td class="labelAndCheckBox na width130">
        <input id="naConcursoConstrucaocb" type="checkbox" />
        <label id="lblnaAncConEmp">Não Disponível</label>
      </td>
    </tr>  

    <tr>
      <td class="clearBoth labelAndValue width260">
        <label id="lblAdjEmp">Adjudicação da empreitada</label>
        <div class="calendar">
          <input id="dataAdjudicacaoConst" type="text" class="tdData" />
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>  

    <tr>
      <td class="labelAndCheckBox na width130">
        <input id="naAdjudicacaoConstcb" type="checkbox" />
        <label id="lblnaAdjEmp">Não Disponível</label>
      </td>
    </tr>  

    <tr>
      <td class="clearBoth labelAndValue width260">
        <label id="lblRcpProvObra">Recepção provisória da obra</label>
        <div class="calendar">
          <input id="dataRecepcaoProvisoria" type="text" class="tdData" />
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>  

    <tr>
      <td class="labelAndCheckBox na width130">
        <input id="naRecepcaoProvisoriacb" type="checkbox" />
        <label id="lblnaRcpProvObra">Não Disponível</label>
      </td>
    </tr>  

    <tr>
      <td class="clearBoth labelAndValue width260">
        <label id="lblIngEdfHsp">Inauguração do Edifício Hospitalar</label>
        <div class="calendar">
          <input id="dataInauguracao" type="text" class="tdData" />
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>  

    <tr>
      <td class="labelAndCheckBox na width130">
        <input id="naInauguracaocb" type="checkbox" />
        <label id="lblnaIngEdfHsp">Não Disponível</label>
      </td>
    </tr>  

    <tr>
      <td class="clearBoth labelAndValue width260">
        <label id="lblRcpDefObra">Recepção definitiva da obra</label>
        <div class="calendar">
          <input id="dataRecepcaoDefinitiva" type="text" class="tdData" />
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>  

    <tr>
      <td class="labelAndCheckBox na width130">
        <input id="naRecepcaoDefinitivacb" type="checkbox" />
        <label id="lblnaRcpDefObra">Não Disponível</label>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>



